# Not Writing out SaveFileDialog to the InputBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
Sub StoreUserData2()
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() Then InputBox(MessageStor, TitleStor, SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog)
    WriteUserFile()
End Sub
```

It allows me to browse and/or create a file, but when I click the save button it transfers the new files directory to anothe savefiledialog box. I cant get it to close the search and place the path in the InputBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `ShowDialog` again in the `InputBox` parameter.
This shows the dialog again.  (as you can expect from the name)

You're probably looking for the `FileName` property.

Comment: Edited to remove line of code that wasnt needed. Still Working on getting it to list in InputBox instead of Dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call the showdialog method twice, just save the result from the first call.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx)

---

Sorry, wrong link.  Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx)